# How to access all this characters json by react.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, nested

How how to access this all characters?

```
data: [{
  "url": "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/823",
  "name": "Petyr Baelish",
  "culture": "Valemen",
  "born": "In 268 AC, at the Fingers",
  "died": "",
  "titles": [
    "Master of coin (formerly)",
    "Lord Paramount of the Trident",
    "Lord of Harrenhal",
    "Lord Protector of the Vale"
  ],
  "aliases": [
    "Littlefinger"
  ],
  "father": "",
  "mother": "",
  "spouse": "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/688",
  "allegiances": [
    "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses/10",
    "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses/11"
  ],
  "books": [
    "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/books/1",

  ],
  "povBooks": [],
  "tvSeries": [
    "Season 1",
    "Season 2",
    "Season 3",
    "Season 4",
    "Season 5"
  ],
  "playedBy": [
    "Aidan Gillen"
  ]
}]

render() {
    var { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Sample data block</h1>
        {this.state.data.map(function(item, i) {
          return <h3 key={'data-'+ i}>{data.title}</h3>
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Do you want any specific key or full json in react component?

Comment: Thanks for reply sir I want to access full json

Answer (score 0):

you have used the data variable but haven't assigned it to state? Please assign it to state. For Example;

```
constructor(){
  this.state = {
  data: [{
  "url": "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/823",
  "name": "Petyr Baelish",
  "culture": "Valemen",
  "born": "In 268 AC, at the Fingers",
  "died": "",
  "titles": [
    "Master of coin (formerly)",
    "Lord Paramount of the Trident",
    "Lord of Harrenhal",
    "Lord Protector of the Vale"
  ],
  "aliases": [
    "Littlefinger"
  ],
  "father": "",
  "mother": "",
  "spouse": "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/characters/688",
  "allegiances": [
    "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses/10",
    "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/houses/11"
  ],
  "books": [
    "https://www.anapioficeandfire.com/api/books/1",

  ],
  "povBooks": [],
  "tvSeries": [
    "Season 1",
    "Season 2",
    "Season 3",
    "Season 4",
    "Season 5"
  ],
  "playedBy": [
    "Aidan Gillen"
  ]
  }]
}
}
```

After that you will be able to access json values by this.state.data[0]['title']
what you can do with your loop is change something like

```
{
  this.state.data.map(function(item) {
    return item.titles.map(function(title, i){
      return <h3 key={'data-'+ i}>{title}</h3>
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOVerflow, perhaps you could add a little explanation why is that needed - it may improve you answer.

Comment: You need to set data in state this.state ={ data: your object} before you access in it render.

Comment: Thanks for consider Zulqarnain Hanif.and its good but let me know how to access full json?